# Can't read special characters like ï or â

Tags: r

[image]

I'm having problems importing datasets that contains special characters. 
At this moment, I am using the following code to import the data:

```
alias <- read.csv("C:Documents/alias.csv",  na.strings = "", sep = ",", header=TRUE,
                  colClasses=c(id="character"), fileEncoding="UTF-8")
```

This works fine until a special character comes up like ï or â, R just stops reading the next rows. I only found complex answers to this problem that I did not understand. I found answers how to convert these special characters after they are imported, but for me, the problem is that it stops importing. I have to find a way so that R keeps importing data without stopping.

The picture shows what I get after importing the data. The next variable is not imported, because it stopped at the character after lego-su.

There are some related topics to my problem like this one: [Reading special characters like ÆØÅ into R (Rstudio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271849/reading-special-characters-like-%C3%86%C3%98%C3%85-into-r-rstudio). I don't know how this local stuff works or how I can integrate this into my problem. Or maybe there is another problem different to that one.

Comment: Can you please provide an example input file, so that we can attempt to replicate your issue?

Comment: I can't give a part of the data because it's confidential. I'll give a sample row where it goes wrong. The data has 3 columns, separated by a comma: 5943001228411622751,"https://www.site.be/e/nl/dl/lego-suâ€‹per-heroes-76044-hetâ€‹-duel-van-de-helden-â€‹146140",(null). In this case, R stops reading at the â character.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue on Ubuntu, either in RStudio or in a stand-alone R shell. The entry loads fine for me. Can you update your original question with links to the "complex answers to this problem that I did not understand" that you found? It might help determine the cause of the issue.